# How to change link color in UITextView in xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

We have created a clickable text in UITextView by using this code

```
   var urlString = @"<a href=""https://www.google.com"" >Google</a>";
        var documentAttributes = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes { DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML };
        NSError error = null;
        var attributedString = new NSAttributedString(NSData.FromString(urlString, NSStringEncoding.UTF8), documentAttributes, ref error);
        // Should really check the NSError before applying

        MyTextView.AttributedText = attributedString;
```

but its showing by default blue color for the link and underlined text. We want to change the color for the text and also remove underline. 
Please guide/help me to implement this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change these properties just adding UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor and  UIStringAttributeKey.UnderlineStyl to your dictionary and set it to WeakLinkTextAttributes property

```
var key1 = UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor;
var value1 = UIColor.Red;

var key2 = UIStringAttributeKey.UnderlineStyle;
var value2 = new NSNumber(0); // 0 without underline 1 with underline

var dict = new NSDictionary(key1, value1, key2, value2);

var urlString = @"<a href=""https://www.google.com"" >Google</a>";
var documentAttributes = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes { 
           DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML };
NSError error = null;
var attributedString = new NSAttributedString(NSData.FromString(urlString, NSStringEncoding.UTF8), documentAttributes, ref error);

yourTextView.AttributedText = attributedString;
yourTextView.WeakLinkTextAttributes = dict;
```

Comment: Hello,
Link color has been changed but underline still displayed. We have put NSNumber(0) but its not working.

Comment: ok lets update the answer and use the same documentAttributes than you.

Comment: just copy the same code that I answered here and has to work

Comment: We have just copy and paste your code as it is but still showing underline. I don't know why..

Comment: Update: We have fix this by adding one more key in NSDictionary

 `var key3 = UIStringAttributeKey.UnderlineColor;
            var value3 = UIColor.Clear;`
Thank you Ricardo