# How to remove underline from a hyperlink UITextView control in Xamarin.ios?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have to remove underline from a hyperlink in UITextview. Can any one help me.
I am using this code to remove but its not working, Please see below...

```
    var key1 = new NSMutableString();
    key1.SetString(new NSString("NSColor"));
    var value1 = UIColor.Orange;    //its working

    var key2 = new NSMutableString();
    key2.SetString(new NSString("NSUnderline"));
    var value2 = new NSNumber(0);   //its not working

    var dict = new NSDictionary(key1, value1, key2, value2);

    MyTesxtView.WeakLinkTextAttributes = dict;
```

Please help/guide to remove underline in hyperlink From UITextview in xamarin.ios

Comment: did u try this `var attrString = new NSAttributedString("yourlink",new UIStringAttributes { StrikethroughStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.None });
            MyTesxtView.AttributedText = attrString;`

Comment: you already has the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52591662/how-to-change-link-color-in-uitextview-in-xamarin-ios/52595966?noredirect=1#comment92259989_52595966

Comment: Hi Recardo, 
Sorry to say but we have just copy and paste your code that you suggested in above link but its not working. Underline is still showing.

Comment: Hello Arvind,
Can you please tell me  proper format for NSAttributedString parameter to make a Hyperlink? I am very new in xamarin.ios.

Comment: @SumitMishra - The above code I have written seems in proper format there should be no confusion. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Arvindraja , Yes I have tried your code and its remove underline, but its also become a text. We need a clickable hyperlink against these url without underline. I think you can understand what I want to say..

Comment: @SumitMishra - Change color of that text & make click event of your control to navigate on the same link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello we have fixed this issue by adding one more key in NSDictionary,

`var key3 = UIStringAttributeKey.UnderlineColor;
var value3 = UIColor.Clear;`