# iOS: NSMutableAttributedString.AddAttributes not rendered. (Xamarin)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xamarin.ios

I am trying to change the style of a link in a UILabel in Xamarin.iOS.
I wrote the following code and the NSMutableAttributedString is updated correctly.
However the updated style is not rendered.
Am I missing something?

I am testing on the iOS Simulator.

```cs
mutableHtmlString.EnumerateAttribute(linkAttributeName, new NSRange(0, mutableHtmlString.Length), NSAttributedStringEnumeration.LongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired,
    (NSObject value, NSRange range, ref bool stop) =>
    {
        var attrHyperlink = new UIStringAttributes
        {
            UnderlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.None,
            ForegroundColor = UIColor.Red,
        };

        if (value != null && value is NSUrl url)
        {
            mutableHtmlString.AddAttributes(attrHyperlink, range);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@$"XXX: {mutableHtmlString}");
        }               
    });
control.AttributedText = mutableHtmlString;
```

NSUnderlineStyle.PatternDash is rendered correctly.
Also KerningAdjustment and UnderlineColor.

Is this limitation of UILabel?

Comment: I had answered a similar question, take a look on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52591662/how-to-change-link-color-in-uitextview-in-xamarin-ios/52595966#52595966

Comment: @RicardoRomo Sorry I am using UiLabel not UiTextView. I updated the question. Thank you tho.

Comment: You could use UITextView instead of UILabel  and set the `UserInteractionEnabled` as false .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT hi, it's a custom renderer for labels, so I cannot use the TextView (I think), also I need user interactions https://github.com/matteobortolazzo/HtmlLabelPlugin/blob/dev/src/HtmlLabel/iOS/Renderer.cs

Comment: In forms you could use Editor instead of Label .

Comment: That's a big breaking change, and it could compromise other functionalities and I doubt the end result would look the same. Also the only issue here is with iOS and the attributed string.

Comment: Could you share a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT in the repository there is a test app, just run that and you will see https://github.com/matteobortolazzo/HtmlLabelPlugin

Comment: You could check the issue report of the plugin in github, link style will support in next release .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT That's me

Comment: Solution found. It's an intended limitation of UILabel to keep consistency. But removing the NSLink attribute solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From Apple**: To promote consistency, the intended behavior is for ranges that represent links (specified via NSLinkAttributeName) to be drawn using the default link appearance. So the current behavior is the expected behavior.

So this mean it's an UILabel limitation and it's intentional.

However, there is a workaround. Just replace *NSLink* with a custom attribute.

```cs
mutableHtmlString.EnumerateAttribute(linkAttributeName, new NSRange(0, mutableHtmlString.Length), NSAttributedStringEnumeration.LongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired,
    (NSObject value, NSRange range, ref bool stop) =>
    {
        var attrHyperlink = new UIStringAttributes
        {
            UnderlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.None,
            ForegroundColor = UIColor.Red,
        };

        if (value != null && value is NSUrl url)
        {
            mutableHtmlString.AddAttribute(customAttributeName, value, range);
            mutableHtmlString.RemoveAttribute("NSLink", range);
            mutableHtmlString.AddAttributes(attrHyperlink, range);
        }               
    });
control.AttributedText = mutableHtmlString;
```

The you can use `customAttributeName` to find the string if needed.

Thanks to https://exceptionshub.com/color-attribute-is-ignored-in-nsattributedstring-with-nslinkattributename.html